# Accessing HTML loaded through Angular Component

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am showing a HTML Page loaded from my mySql Database and loading it in my angular component through .innerHTML. Looks something like this

```
get(): void {
this.dataServ.getMds(this.formName).subscribe((value: any) => {
  this.dataSource = value;
  this.form = '<div ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formController">' + this.dataSource + '</div>';
}); }
```

With my HTML looking like this

```
<div [innerHtml]="form | sanitizehtml">
</div>
```

So I make a request to my backend, get a string back which is the entire HTML code I need. Then load it into my angular and then show it through innerHTML. So far so good but when trying to get values from the HTML code or trying to call a function it doesn't seem to get to Angular and just tells me the function is not defined.

Part of the HTML I am loading with the function "onChange" being called at onclick

```
<input type="checkbox" id="boxal" name="test1" [checked]="select" onclick="onChange()" (click)="onChange()">
```

The function in my angular component I am trying to call:

```
  onChange() {
console.log("TEST")}
```

Chrome console puts out:

> blank:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: onChange is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

My goal would be to be able to dynamically load a HTML form into my angular component and then get the values from the filled out form back.

Comment: Few strange things here. You seem to be using Angular, but the snippet your loading in innerHtml looks like AngularJS (the form bit) but then you show the input.. which looks like Angular again. In short, content in innerHtml will not just be rendered by Angular.

Comment: What happens if you remove onclick="onChange() ?

Comment: @MikeOne okok so it is like i thought. Do you by chance know a solution in which i can dynamically load HTML code into a part of my angular application? And thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @SPdeWit then I don't have any way to see if the HTML I am loading is able to use my angular component